# Detecting if beforeunload event was cancelled by an unrelated function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple function to show a spinner overlay while a new page request is being made.

```
$(window).on("beforeunload", function() {
  $('#nav-spinner').show();
});
```

This works perfectly.. but, it is used on a complex WordPress site and there are other (third party) components that also use this event to sometimes cancel the navigation (for instance, a confirmation when navigating away from a partially filled form).

Is there any way to determine if another function cancelled the page unload so I can remove my overlay immediately when they are remaining on the page.

I would like to do this when an actual navigation is cancelled - using a timer to remove the overlay will result in either the overlay being hidden prematurely or remaining for longer than it should.

Comment: there is no event for cancelling....

Answer (score 2):

## Test Case that shows the problem

So the following code shows what you have currently. I am setting the background red since it is a minimum amount of code.

```js
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function(event) {
  document.body.classList.add("red");
});

// 3rd party code that is showing the "are you sure"
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  event.returnValue = 'I am 3rd party code';
});
```

```css
.red {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <button>Click Me then click "Cancel"</button>
</form>
```

## Solving the problem

So now that we have the test case for what is wrong. The background should NOT remain red when the user clicks cancel. So how can we detect it? Well there is NO events that tells you what the user did.

So the only thing you can do would be to add a timer to remove what you added when the user cancels it. So if they click cancel, the timer runs and removes it.

But how do we keep it there if they do not cancel it?  We use unload to kill the timeout that hides it. So remove the timeout and it will not fire.

```js
var timer
// update the page as page exits
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function(event) {
  document.body.classList.add("red");
  // if this timer runs, it means beforeunload was cancelled 
  timer = window.setTimeout( function () {
    document.body.classList.remove("red");
  }, 50);
});
   // remove the timer when the pages finally exits so the class is not removed.
window.addEventListener("unload", function(event) {
  window.clearTimeout(timer)
})


 // 3rd party code that is showing the "are you sure"
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  event.returnValue = 'I am 3rd party code';
});
```

```css
.red {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <button>Click Me then click "Cancel"</button>
</form>
```

You may have to play with the timeout millisecond values. The flash of content for showing could be lessened with a transition, but hopefully the browser does not kill that unload.

Comment: My overlay needs to stay on the page until the page actually unloads (this may be several seconds depending on the operation being performed server-side) so unfortunately a timer will not suffice.

Comment: Which is what the code would do... The timer runs when it is cancelled, it is removed when unload is called. Probably have to play with the milliseconds..... There is no events, so you have to get creative.

Comment: It looks to me like it will remove the overlay on the unload, but that is not the problem. I need to remove it if the unload is cancelled. Am I missing something?

Comment: NO.... it removes the timeout if unload fires......you are misreading the code. TRY IT

Comment: Sorry, but I think you are misreading the question. Showing the overlay is not a problem. The problem is that I need to hide the overlay if something external to my code prevents unload. I tested your code and all it does is throw up a confirmation on every page change. It would be easy if I was doing the confirmation myself, but I'm not.

Comment: If there is no beforeunload(cancelled) event then I need to look at another solution, maybe a way to find and monkey patch other functions that are hooking beforeunload?

Comment: This code is doing what you said......It said other things are adding onbeflore unload so it is the confirmation.  The code will set the style of the background to red when unbeforeunload is detected. If the user cancels it, the timeout runs and removes the background color. If the user does not cancel it, than the timeout is removed and the color stays red.

Comment: "....other functions that are hooking beforeunload? " not sure how that will help, You are still going to not know if they cancelled it. Unless you are saying they are blowing away your event listener....

Comment: My event listener fires on beforeunload correctly and shows my overlay. Now, if another script (not at all related to mine or written by me) happens to also hook beforeunload and it cancels the page unload, then and only then, my overlay needs to be hidden.

Comment: Appreciate your input, I really do. But no, that is not what that code is doing.

Comment: lol..... I added comments to explain it. Basically if the setTineout was not there, it is the same code you have to show the dialog and having it stick.....

Comment: There I added a test case that shows your issue. Run that code and click cancel. You will see the red background. Than run the second one and click cancel. You will see the red background flash as it is added and than removed by the timeout..

Comment: I get what you'tr trying to do, I really do, but as I said, it may be several seconds between the beforeunload and the unload events... it is not acceptable to have a timer set for up to 10000ms because the overlay would remain on screen for far too long after cancel.

Comment: Why would it several seconds between beforeunload and unload... That does not make any sense. That is not how the browser works. The timer here is just to hide your dialog if they click cancel. I am going to bed so I am out.

Comment: Because "unload" does not appear to fire until after the server responds to the new page request (after server-side work is done). Gotta run now but happy to continue this in chat later. cheers.

Comment: This is desired behavior too, I want my overlay to show while the request is pending.

Comment: From another post; "It's a browser-specific behaviour. Chrome and FF will send a GET requst BEFORE onunload is fired, IE8 will execute onunload first. Not sure, how the other browser handle it."